# import CSV into a list, with a variable number of comments in Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have several CSV files, that do not have a header row but do have a variable number of free text comment lines at the start. Free text meaning with Spaces ","s and anything you can think of

All the comment lines begin with a #

After the comments, the CSV part is fixed at 4 columns, but is of variable length, up to 86400 lines.

I am trying to read the file, ignoring the comment line and put columns 1,2 from the remaining CSV into an array.

I have been trying to process line by line and also with a `dictreader` filter, but not having much luck.

> ## Instrument: Mark2
>
> ```
> #Type: Phase
> #Start: 2000/03/29 19:33:43
> #StartPC: 2013/01/15 17:31:06
> #UTCOffset: 0:00
> #Tau: 1
> #MTIE1: 0000000010,0000000021,0000000033,0000000082,0000000168,0000000386,0000001007,0000001920,0000003720,0000007308,000001
> 4526,0000028941,0000000000
> #MTIE2: 0000000002,0000000006,0000000013,0000000047,0000000116,0000000339,0000001001,0000001985,0000003954,0000007824,000001
> 5200,0000029773,0000000000
> 954358423.902,-315,-363,0000
> 954358424.902,-315,-363,0000
> 954358425.902,-319,-363,0000
> 954358426.902,-319,-363,0000
> 954358427.902,-317,-363,0000
> 954358428.902,-318,-363,0000
> 954358429.902,-320,-363,0000
> 954358430.902,-321,-362,0000
> 954358431.902,-324,-363,0000
> 954358432.902,-326,-363,0000
> 954358433.902,-329,-363,0000
> 954358434.902,-332,-362,0000
> 954358435.902,-331,-363,0000
> 954358436.902,-331,-363,0000
> 954358437.902,-336,-363,0000
> 954358438.902,-336,-363,0000
> 954358439.903,-334,-363,0000
> 954358440.903,-336,-363,0000
> ```

My most sucessful code has been as below,

however it returns more data per line then I expect. Also I am not sure how to read it into an array after that

> {'954358423.902,-315,-363,0000': '954418183.599,-60158,-60125,0000'}
>   {'954358423.902,-315,-363,0000': '954418184.599,-60158,-60126,0000'}
>   {'954358423.902,-315,-363,0000': '954418185.599,-60156,-60127,0000'}
>   {'954358423.902,-315,-363,0000': '954418186.599,-60157,-60128,0000'}

```
from itertools 
import dropwhile 
import csv 
fname = "file1.csv"

with open(fname) as fin:
    start = dropwhile(lambda L: L.lower().lstrip().startswith('#'), fin)
    for row in csv.DictReader(start, delimiter='\t'):
        print row
```

Comment: Can you share some code that you have tried so far?

Comment: It would help if you could include some of the data and what you've tried in Python.

Comment: It's not obvious why this is giving you any problem - either with or without `csvreader` it sounds pretty doable - so you need to explain your problem more.

Comment: csv.reader does not care if the input file is really a file it just wants an iterable which spills out strings. With that in mind... You could have a method/function that receives the Filename in input, loops 1 line at a time, if it's not commented it `yields` the line else `continue`...

Comment: Your instrument file seems to have wrapped the last two comment lines.  Also your code seems to have an extra line break in the first line.

Comment: The last 2 comment lines are very long, so they appear wrapped in this example

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically fine but for some reason you are using a `DictReader` when you should be using a `reader`.  DictReaders expect there to be a header 
line and you don't have one.

However, you then have the problem that you have specified `"\t"` as a delimiter whereas your file is delimited with `","`.  Fixing that as well makes it all work:

```
from itertools import dropwhile 
import csv 
fname = "file1.csv"

with open(fname) as fin:
    start = dropwhile(lambda L: L.lower().lstrip().startswith('#'), fin)
    for row in csv.reader(start, delimiter=','):
        print row
```

Comment: Many thanks, but why from an original 4 colums, do I now get 8 ? and i a different order to the original.    {'-363': '-60127', '0000': '0000', '-315': '-60156', '954358423.902': '954418185.599'}
{'-363': '-60128', '0000': '0000', '-315': '-60157', '954358423.902': '954418186.599'}

Comment: The output you quote is still a dictionary, not a list.  Are you still using a DictReader?